# Modify a piece of PHP code

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I have this:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlLink($this->viewer()->getHref(), $this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon')); ?>
```

That generates an HTML code like:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/john">
  <img src="http://www.domain.com/thumb_0205.jpg" alt="" class="thumb_icon item_photo_user thumb_icon">
</a>
```

Now, what I am trying to do, is to add:

```
<?php echo $this->viewer()->getTitle(); ?> //This will generate the member's name, like "John Doe"
```

to the code above, to generate an HTML code like:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/john">
  <img src="http://www.domain.com/thumb_0205.jpg" alt="" class="thumb_icon item_photo_user thumb_icon">
  <span>John Doe</span>
</a>
```

Anyway I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Sure you can, check the documentation or source for `htmlLink` to see if you can pass in other arguments; or create your own version of it that adds the extra information you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlLink(
    $this->viewer()->getHref(), 
    $this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon') . '<span>' . $this->viewer()->getTitle() . '</span>'
); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Guessing, this should work:

```
<?php echo $this->htmlLink($this->viewer()->getHref(), $this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon').'<span>'. $this->viewer()->getTitle().'</span>'); ?>
```

Just append the extra string to the second argument of htmlLink.

```
HtmlLink($href, $text, $title = "", array $attribs = array());
```